# How to Run Android default Alarm Clock application?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-source, alarm, android-alarms

[image]I couldn't run the source code given @ https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock.git
in Android Studio.

The above cloned project is not a gradle project. What should I do exactly to build the app in Android Studio?

Just to run Alarm clock application, do I need to have the setup & requirments mentioned @ https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html

Comment: post code then only anyone will help

Comment: @maven: you can find the code @ https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock.git as mentioned in the question.  :)

Comment: The only way to reproduce the errors above is to clone the repo and trying to open it. I think I state it clearly in the question. And there's a print screen also for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I was able to clone and run the Android default Alarm app available @ https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker

and got the confidence that I do not need the setup + requirments (150GB free space with 16GB RAM) mentioned @ https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html

Though it's not a gradle project, we can migrate it as a Gradle Project via Android Studio as mentioned by @PriyankPatel in the above comments.

But there were lots of errors and all those errors were dependency issues and it took me about a week to find out why and how to get rid of everything.

Below is a list of all the dependencies I needed to run this app without errors.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.citux:datetimepicker:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.0.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.0.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.1'
}
```

Make sure the compile sdk and build tool versions match above dependencies as well.

Hope this will help someone who tries to work on an app in Android Open Source Project.

Comment: was that project useful to you?

Comment: Yes indeed. I ended up with a wonderful app called ShutUp! 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wizardsofm.deskclock

Comment: Beautiful app, rated 5 starts! I cloned the repo, added dependencies, but I cant run my project, there is no main activity to run. Could please gimme more details about properly migrating that project to android studio? Any info helps, thanks in advance!

Comment: Which one you used?
1.Create a new empty Android Studio project and copy your existing source code into the directories associated with the new project. For more information, see Migrate by creating a new empty project.
2.Manually create a new Gradle build file for your project and then import the project and new build file into Android Studio. For more information see Migrate by creating a custom Gradle build file.

Comment: @Vaclovas, Thanks for the ratings. After you clone the repo did you see a directory called Deskclock1. That's the project you need to open and run from Android Studio. you may need to migrate that project to Android studio compatible (in order to run with gradle) so please check https://coderwall.com/p/npki6q/migrate-existing-android-project-to-gradle
The activities are at DeskClock1->app->src_main->java. You will find classes such as AlarmActivity.java

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! You earlier pointer to datetimepicker and I don't know why I tryed cloning it! Cloned DeskClock, added dependencies, built! thanks you so much man!

Comment: great to hear.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the `Alarm Clock` app from the Android github mirror.

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock

Or  Android `Desk Clock` app from the `CyanogenMod` mirror.

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_DeskClock

Checkout below articles for migrate existing android project to android studio.

[Migrate to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html)

[Migrate existing android project to gradle](https://coderwall.com/p/npki6q/migrate-existing-android-project-to-gradle)

Comment: This is what he did. His question is how to build and run it since it is not using Gradle to build.

Comment: @Priyank, yes as karakuri stated I already downloaded the app, but unfortunately couldn't run since it's not a gradle project. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @madu check my updated answer for migrating existing android project to android studio.

Comment: I already migrated to gradle. but doing so gives me weird errors like : No resource identifier found for attribute 'rowCount' in package 'com.android.deskclock' 
I edited my question by attaching an image in my above question.

Comment: I was able to reduce the number of errors by adding appropriate dependencies. But now it gives few errors as below,
package cyanogenmod.app does not exist,
cannot find symbol variable ProfileManager,
cannot find symbol class TimePickerDialog...

Comment: Checkout here for [How to Download/Compile Specific Parts of a ROM](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/downloadcompile-specific-rom-parts)